# Значение анекдота про ведро раков

Tags: значение-слов

> Приходит один мужик к другому.
>   — Петрович, помнишь, у тебя зимой жена пропала?
>   — Ну.
>   — У меня две новости: плохая и хорошая...
>   — Давай плохую.
>   — Мы ее нашли. В реке утонула.
>   — А хорошая?
>   — Мы с нее ведро раков сняли.

В чем смысл этого анекдота? Что лежит в его основе?

Comment: Жена утонула — плохо, а вот собранное ведро раков с трупа под пиво неплохо зайдет)

Comment: @СтепанПопов вот я об этом подумал, но как-то корявенько составлен анекдот ) весь смысл в _жене под пиво_?

Comment: Все может быть) Может, другие участники найдут что-то еще.

Answer (score 3):

Раки, как известно, падальщики. Для ловца раков найти затопленный труп (как правило, животного) - большая удача: там всегда будет много раков. Но удачей это можно называть только до тех пор, пока речь не пойдет о чем-то настолько плохом, что это уже не будет казаться удачей.
Анекдот как раз и построен на явном несоответствии степени негативности плохой новости и "позитивности" хорошей.

Comment: Интересно, спасибо! Но почему тогда жена и зимой?

Comment: Найти человека, провалившегося зимой под лед, очень непросто.
Именно поэтому герой анекдота ранее не знал, что именно произошло зимой с его женой, пока друзья не сообщили ему две новости.

Answer (score 3):

Этот анекдот близок к категории так называемого черного юмора, такие анекдоты построены на абсурдной бесчувственности персонажей к чужим страданиям, горю. Пример:

Поднимается мужик по леснице, смотрит: другой мужик тянет девочку за ноги, у нее голова об ступеньки дынс-дынс. Он говорит:
— Мужик, ну что же ты делаешь?! Ну, смотри, у девочки сейчас пaнамочка спaдет.
— Ничо, не спaдет, я ее гвоздиком прибил.

Герои анекдота про раков бесчувствены не абсолютно, но в достаточно абсурдной степени.